# How to detect mobile type and is mobile for a request?

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, mobile, httprequest

I want to detect if a request came from Mobile Device, and if it is, I want to know the Mobile Device Model. When I use android phones, for example, I get wrong values.

I tried using:

```
System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser;
return browser.IsMobileDevice;
```

and:

```
System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser;
return browser.MobileDeviceModel;
```

but when I use Galaxy S2 or HTC, I get false for IsMobileDevice, and unknown for MobileDeviceModel.

I tried:

```
System.Web.Mobile.MobileCapabilities mc = (System.Web.Mobile.MobileCapabilities)HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser;
string deviceModel = mc.MobileDeviceModel;
string browser = mc.Browser;
```

but it is the same.

how can I detect IsMobile and MobileDeviceModel correctly?

Comment: I was using [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) for some time for device detection and was quite happy with it. Unfortunately, it is not free anymore...

Answer (score 3):

I normally use Regex to detect mobile which works perfectly, see below:

```
String u = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
     bool mobileUser = false;

                Regex b = new Regex("android.+mobile|avantgo|bada\\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
                Regex v = new Regex("1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\\-(n|u)|c55\\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\\-5|g\\-mo|go(\\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\\-(m|p|t)|hei\\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\\-c|ht(c(\\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\\-|\\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\\-|e\\/|\\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\\-w|m3ga|m50\\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\\-g|qa\\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\\-[2-7]|i\\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\\-|oo|p\\-)|sdk\\/|se(c(\\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\\-|shar|sie(\\-|m)|sk\\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\\-|v\\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\\-|tdg\\-|tel(i|m)|tim\\-|t\\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\\-|m3|m5)|tx\\-9|up(\\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\\-|2|g)|yas\\-|your|zeto|zte\\-", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
                if (u.Length > 4)
                {
                    if (b.IsMatch(u) | v.IsMatch(u.Substring(0, 4)))
                    {
                        mobileUser = true;
                    }
                }

                if (mobileUser) //mobile user!!
                {
                    mobileSiteUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MobileSiteURL"];

                    Response.Redirect(mobileSiteUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                 }
```

Comment: Thanks @Sam1. What is it u? UserAgent property?

Comment: @Sam1 why bitwise inclusive or | instead of logical || in control statement? does v.IsMatch(uSubstring(0, 4)) really need to execute in any case?